# If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x_{0}$, and $g$ is non-zero on $X$, then $f/g$ is also differentiable at $x_{0}$ and . . .

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, alternative-proof

If $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x_{0}$, and $g$ is non-zero on $X$, then $f/g$ is also differentiable at $x_{0}$ and
\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{f'(x_{0})g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})g'(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})^{2}}
\end{align*}

**MY ATTEMPT**

According to the definition of derivative, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{(f/g)(x) - (f/g)(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}} = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x)g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})g(x)}{(x-x_{0})g(x)g(x_{0})}
\end{align*}
On the other hand, we have that
\begin{align*}
f(x)g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})g(x) & = f(x)g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})g(x_{0}) + f(x_{0})g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})g(x)\\\\
& = [f(x) - f(x_{0})]g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})[g(x) - g(x_{0})]
\end{align*}

Consequently, we have that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{(f/g)(x) - (f/g)(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}} & = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{[f(x) - f(x_{0})]g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})[g(x) - g(x_{0})]
}{(x-x_{0})g(x)g(x_{0})}\\\\
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{[f(x) - f(x_{0})]g(x_{0})}{(x-x_{0})g(x)g(x_{0})} - \lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}\frac{f(x_{0})[g(x) - g(x_{0})]}{(x-x_{0})g(x)g(x_{0})}\\\\
& = \frac{f'(x_{0})g(x_{0}) - f(x_{0})g'(x_{0})}{g(x_{0})^{2}}
\end{align*}

and we are done.

I would like to know if someone could provide an alternative solution to this problem. Any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: Quite good, right to the point. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule for other proofs.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I will consult it.